# need help to exctract and filter excel data using a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I want to know if there is a way to extract and filter(select only some columns and rows) data from excel file using a batch script. I have already looked for answers in google but in vain.

Comment: not possible with simple batch.You'll need jscript/vbscript hybrid , powershell or selfcomiled .net

Comment: i need to do other things in the same batch: extract excel file from FTP server, filter that file and iinsert the data into a database. So i don t know if powershell for example can do all this things

Comment: yes it can...Its far more powerful than the batch.

Answer (score 1):

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H0001

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=""C:\Users\David Candy\Documents\Alcohol.xls"";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

objRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM `C:\Users\David Candy\Documents\Alcohol`.`Sheet1$` `Sheet1$`", _
          objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText


Do Until objRecordset.EOF
    Wscript.Echo "Name: " & objRecordset.Fields.Item("Price") 
    objRecordset.MoveNext
 Loop
```

Run with cscript

```
cscript //nologo c:\pathto\script.vbs
```

It writes Price column to the console

Comment: Don't know. I use 32 bit. I run 16 bit programs.

Comment: There are at least two 32 bit drivers for at some versions of excel. This web site gives all connection strings for excel - https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

Comment: The easiest way to find  the available drivers - odbcad32.exe->drivers tab.Win8x64 has the excel connector but text driver is missing.Still available in Wow64 version.

Comment: Thank u for the answer. But i have already switched to powershell. If u have any ideas how does taht work on powershell